# JMRTD : Why there is a difference in CAP gererated by build from eclipse and cap file available in JMRTD folder

Tags: eclipse, smartcard, javacard

I have downloaded the JMRTD applet and source files from the following link :-

- [https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jmrtd/jmrtd/0.5.13/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmrtd/files/passportapplet/0.0.2b/http://)
- [https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmrtd/files/passportapplet/0.0.2b/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmrtd/files/passportapplet/0.0.2b/http://)

**My issue**

There is a difference in CAP file generated by eclipse and CAP file available in passportapplet-bin.zip from the second link.

I'm using jmrtd-0.5.5.jar (190.8 kB) and Java card 2.0.2 libraries .jar files to build the JMRTD source code.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't expect that .cap files are binary comparable. Basically the main .cap files are .zip files (similar to how .jar files are actually .zip files underneath). The main .cap file stores multiple files that also end with .cap. These contain the data that is actually send to the card. For instance Methods.cap will contain most of the code.

However because the main .cap file is a .zip file this also means that it could be re-ordered. Besides that, the .cap file will also contain meta data such as file creation data. And there are of course several options to deal with, such as the inclusion of debugging info. It is therefore to be expected that .cap files will always differ when rebuilding.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I was traveling for my job.

Comment: **I want to ask one more thing,What if the build is generated using same source file and libraries.Than Cap file generated and Cap file given should be same?**

Comment: Nope. Same issue. If would unpack the .cap file then I would expect the files themselved to be the same if the same compiler is used. But in principle the method order could for instance be different.

Comment: ... methods may not be the best example though, due to the static linker in the converter. It may of course be that the *internal* .cap files will be the same, but that doesn't mean that they *have to be*.